# How do I query for an Activity that has 3 tags?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

**activity.rb**

**tag.rb**

**tagging.rb**

Tagging is a join model for activity and tag.

I would like to search an Activity that has 2 or more tags. How do I do this in rails?

For example:

I have tag1 = Christmas, tag2 = Florida, tag3 = John

I want to find the Activity where tag1, tag2 and tag3 are present if it exists.

**[EDIT]**

What I ended up doing:

```
tags = [tag1, tag2, tag3]

activities = []
tags.each do |tag|
  activities << tag.activities
end

activities.flatten.group_by { |activity| activity.id }
```

If any of the groups values' size is equal to tags.size then that activity contains all tags.

Comment: What about to add `tags_count` field to `activities` table and query like `Activity.where("tags_count >= 2")`

Comment: you want to just have those activity whose tag count are greater then 2 or u want to search for particular comninations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but this should be a better performant way to achieve it. But there should be an even better way

```
tags_ids = [tag1, tag2, tag3].map(&:id)
ativities_ids = Tagging.where(tag_id: tags_ids).group("activity_id having count(tag_id) = #{tags_ids.size}").select('activity_id').map(&:activity_id)
Activity.find(activities_id)
```

This will get activities that have those tags, but they can have others too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have those activities where a particular tags should exist then try out teh following command

```
selected_activity = Activity.all.select do |activity|
                      %w(Christmas Florida John).all? do |name|
                        activity.tags.include?(name)
                      end 
                    end
```

Once it runs we can always refactor it so as to reduce the number of queries which are fired...

Comment: Thanks. This will get me what I want. I have to find a way to get less queries though...

Comment: I upvoted but it has the N+1 query problem. Use `Activity.includes(:tags)`

Comment: Also check my answer to make the checking for tags included in the query instead of doing it in ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
  Activity.includes(:tags).select{ |act| act.tags.size> 2}
```

Comment: I was thinking about particular combinations. But both your method and Aditya's method help me get what I want. I just have to see how I can make it more efficient.